# using external disc for media files with RewriteRule

Tags: apache-2.4, rewrite

My apache DocumentRoot folder is `$HOME/MyProject/src`. Large external disc is mounted on a server on `/storage` path.

I have a bunch of rewrite rules set on in apache `.conf`. For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/api/media/(.*) /data/$1 [L]
```

With the new external disc in place, rewrite rule should point to actual absolute path on `/storage/myproject/data/$1`, which is not in the `DocumentRoot` path.

I want to use the storage space of external disc for media files. I cannot use the default disc where source code is, because it is too small. What is my best option? Surely this doesn't mean moving source and DocumentRoot to slow HDD external storage.

Comment: and why not using a bind mount?

Comment: thanks. first time bind mount. works great

Comment: so already solved?

Comment: yes. but used symlinks at the end

Comment: `mount --bind /from /to` should not be sich hard?

Comment: because if(when) you do backups, you need to be extra careful to not backup twice

Comment: for that kind exists excludes?